# How to access the UITableView cell in another method in swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

In my `UITableView` I have added 2 types of custom cells

```
let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SINGLECELL") as? TimesheetSingleCellTableViewCell
```

and

```
let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TIMESHEETCELL") as? TimeSheetTableViewCell
```

In each cell I have set the button tag and target like this.

```
cell?.btnTimeChange.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timeChangeWheelClick(btn:)), for: .touchUpInside)
cell?.btnTimeChange.tag=indexPath.row
```

How can I check the whether the cell class which the clicked button belongs to.

eg:

```
if(cell==TimeSheetTableViewCell){}
else if(cell==TimesheetSingleCellTableViewCell){}
```

Please help me.

Comment: How about two separate selectors? Or use a callback closure, that's more convenient (and versatile) than target/action.

Comment: @vadianI think this would be great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `is` function, which tells you if a variable's type is the class you are comparing it to or if it is a subclass.

```
if cell is TimeSheetTableViewCell {

} else if cell is TimesheetSingleCellTableViewCell {

}
```

You can access the cell with the corresponding `IndexPath` using

`let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: button.tag, section: sectionNumber)`

You should also store `indexPath.section` unless you only have a single section, then you can just use 0.

Comment: Thanks. And how can I access the cell using my button tag? I have set the index path to button tag